# Vertical JQuery Tabs with Previous and Next Buttons

Tags: jquery, tabs

I found this tab Jquery plugin, perfect for my site. (http://www.faridesign.net/2012/05/create-a-awesome-vertical-tabbed-content-area-using-css3-jquery/)

1) How can I add multiplie instances of the same script (which currently breaks the plugin)

------My attempt-----
Here is the code I used to attempt to have multiple instances:

```
// this is the original code 
$(function () {
        var items = $('#v-nav>ul>li').each(function () {
            $(this).click(function () {
                //remove previous class and add it to clicked tab
                items.removeClass('p_current');
                $(this).addClass('p_current');
                //hide all content divs and show current one
                $('#v-nav>div.tab-content').hide().eq(items.index($(this))).show('fast'); 
                showTab($(this).attr('tab'));
            });
        });
        showTab("tab_pants1");
        function showTab(tab) {
            $("#v-nav ul li:[tab=" + tab + "]").click();
        } 
    });
```

Here is the associated HTML for the above javascript:

```
<div id="option_container"> 
    <div id="v-nav">
        <ul>
            <li tab="tab_pants1" class="first">STYLE <img src="img/site/check1.png" width="15px" class="check collar"></li>
            <li tab="tab_pants2">BUTTON <img src="img/site/check1.png" width="15px" class="check button"></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
             <div id="option">
                <table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="collarImg"><br><input class="optionCollar" id="optionRadio" type="radio" name="collar" value="1"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="collarImg"><br><input class="optionCollar" id="optionRadio" type="radio" name="collar" value="1"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="collarImg"><br><input class="optionCollar" id="optionRadio" type="radio" name="collar" value="1"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="collarImg"><br><input class="optionCollar" id="optionRadio" type="radio" name="collar" value="1"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="collarImg"><br><input class="optionCollar" id="optionRadio" type="radio" name="collar" value="1"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="collarImg"><br><input class="optionCollar" id="optionRadio" type="radio" name="collar" value="1"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="collarImg"><br><input class="optionCollar" id="optionRadio" type="radio" name="collar" value="1"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="collarImg"><br><input class="optionCollar" id="optionRadio" type="radio" name="collar" value="1"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="collarImg"><br><input class="optionCollar" id="optionRadio" type="radio" name="collar" value="1"></td>
                        <td></td> 
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="collarImg"><br><input class="optionCollar" id="optionRadio" type="radio" name="collar" value="1"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="collarImg"><br><input class="optionCollar" id="optionRadio" type="radio" name="collar" value="1"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="collarImg"><br><input class="optionCollar" id="optionRadio" type="radio" name="collar" value="1"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>    
            </div>
            <div id="option_preview">
                <img src="img/option/collar.png" width="335px">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="option">
                <table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="buttonImg"><br><input class="optionButton" id="optionRadio" type="radio" name="Button" value="1"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="buttonImg"><br><input class="optionButton"  id="optionRadio"type="radio" name="Button" value="1"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="buttonImg"><br><input class="optionButton" id="optionRadio" type="radio" name="Button" value="1"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="buttonImg"><br><input class="optionButton" id="optionRadio"type="radio" name="Button" value="1"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="buttonImg"><br><input class="optionButton" id="optionRadio" type="radio" name="Button" value="1"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="buttonImg"><br><input class="optionButton" id="optionRadio" type="radio" name="Button" value="1"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="buttonImg"><br><input class="optionButton" id="optionRadio" type="radio" name="Button" value="1"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="buttonImg"><br><input class="optionButton" id="optionRadio" type="radio" name="Button" value="1"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="buttonImg"><br><input class="optionButton" id="optionRadio" type="radio" name="Button" value="1"></td>
                        <td></td> 
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="buttonImg"><br><input class="optionButton" id="optionRadio"type="radio" name="Button" value="1"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="buttonImg"><br><input class="optionButton" id="optionRadio" type="radio" name="Button" value="1"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="buttonImg"><br><input class="optionButton" id="optionRadio"type="radio" name="Button" value="1"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>    
            </div>
            <div id="option_preview">
                <img src="img/option/collar.png" width="335px">
            </div>
        </div>  
</div><!--end of option container-->
```

Here is my edit of new code for a new instance

```
$(function () {
        var itemsOption = $('#v-nav>ul>li').each(function () {
            $(this).click(function () {
                //remove previous class and add it to clicked tab
                itemsOption.removeClass('option_current');
                $(this).addClass('option_current');
                //hide all content divs and show current one
                $('#v-nav>div.option-content').hide().eq(itemsOption.index($(this))).show('fast'); 
                showOption($(this).attr('option'));
            });
        });
        showOption("option1");
        function showOption(option) {
            $("#v-nav ul li:[option=" + option + "]").click();
        } 
    });
```

Here is the associated HTML for the second tab system:

```
<div id="option_container"> 
    <div id="v-nav">
        <ul>
            <li option="option1" class="first">STYLE <img src="img/site/check1.png" width="15px" class="check collar"></li>
            <li option="option2" class="last">BUTTON <img src="img/site/check1.png" width="15px" class="check button"></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="option-content">
             <div id="option">
                <table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="collarImg"><br><input class="optionCollar" id="optionRadio" type="radio" name="collar" value="1"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="collarImg"><br><input class="optionCollar" id="optionRadio" type="radio" name="collar" value="1"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="collarImg"><br><input class="optionCollar" id="optionRadio" type="radio" name="collar" value="1"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="collarImg"><br><input class="optionCollar" id="optionRadio" type="radio" name="collar" value="1"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="collarImg"><br><input class="optionCollar" id="optionRadio" type="radio" name="collar" value="1"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="collarImg"><br><input class="optionCollar" id="optionRadio" type="radio" name="collar" value="1"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="collarImg"><br><input class="optionCollar" id="optionRadio" type="radio" name="collar" value="1"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="collarImg"><br><input class="optionCollar" id="optionRadio" type="radio" name="collar" value="1"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="collarImg"><br><input class="optionCollar" id="optionRadio" type="radio" name="collar" value="1"></td>
                        <td></td> 
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="collarImg"><br><input class="optionCollar" id="optionRadio" type="radio" name="collar" value="1"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="collarImg"><br><input class="optionCollar" id="optionRadio" type="radio" name="collar" value="1"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="collarImg"><br><input class="optionCollar" id="optionRadio" type="radio" name="collar" value="1"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>    
            </div>
            <div id="option_preview">
                <img src="img/option/collar.png" width="335px">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="option-content">
            <div id="option">
                <table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="buttonImg"><br><input class="optionButton" id="optionRadio" type="radio" name="Button" value="1"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="buttonImg"><br><input class="optionButton"  id="optionRadio"type="radio" name="Button" value="1"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="buttonImg"><br><input class="optionButton" id="optionRadio" type="radio" name="Button" value="1"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="buttonImg"><br><input class="optionButton" id="optionRadio"type="radio" name="Button" value="1"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="buttonImg"><br><input class="optionButton" id="optionRadio" type="radio" name="Button" value="1"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="buttonImg"><br><input class="optionButton" id="optionRadio" type="radio" name="Button" value="1"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="buttonImg"><br><input class="optionButton" id="optionRadio" type="radio" name="Button" value="1"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="buttonImg"><br><input class="optionButton" id="optionRadio" type="radio" name="Button" value="1"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="buttonImg"><br><input class="optionButton" id="optionRadio" type="radio" name="Button" value="1"></td>
                        <td></td> 
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="buttonImg"><br><input class="optionButton" id="optionRadio"type="radio" name="Button" value="1"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="buttonImg"><br><input class="optionButton" id="optionRadio" type="radio" name="Button" value="1"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" class="buttonImg"><br><input class="optionButton" id="optionRadio"type="radio" name="Button" value="1"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>    
            </div>
            <div id="option_preview">
                <img src="img/option/collar.png" width="335px">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!--end of option container-->
```

The top code works, but the bottom code does not. I have changed all the necessary css classes and IDs, but its not working....
Here is the link to test site I made: http://monarcbrand.com/alpha/test.php

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by multiple instances? All you did was change "tab" to "option"

Comment: @Jay Na I mean to have two different sets of tabs. One Tab system for one thing, another tab system for another

Comment: Sorry I still don't comprehend. Are you talking about having tabs within tabs?

Comment: I edited the question. Here is the tab with error. I should be able two tab system on the same page: http://monarcbrand.com/alpha/test.php

Comment: You **can't** have `#option-container` and `div#v-nav` **twice**. You can use ID only once